# Git keeps adding bin and obj files even though there is an ignorefile

Tags: git, gitignore

I have been working on a POC and now have been asked to upload it to our GitHub. I have done that, but today I notice the `bin` and `obj` folder being included.

So I opened up my `.gitignore` file to check I've added the Visual Studio profile. Which it was.. I could see `[Bb]in/` and `[Oo]bj/` are included.

So I tried to remove the folder from Git by typing:

```
git rm --cached -r [folder]/bin
```

After doing that I saw all the `*dll` being removed, I checked in Team Explorer and noted that the files were all removed.

Committed, and rebuilt to see that all the `bin` files returned...

it's not just one project in the solution. It seems to be all of them doing this. I have my `.gitignore` file in the root of my solution. As well as the .git folder. [Screen shot of folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmtGg.jpg)

- I tried copying the `.gitignore` file to the project folder. didn't work
- I tried adding `**/[Bb]in/` & `**[Bb]in/` .. no change.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

My `.gitignore` is an exact copy of this [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

I reverted my `**/[Bb]in/` changes to see if I broke something.

Comment: `to see that all the bin files returned...` ... where did the files return?  To the filesystem or index?

Comment: Sorry to team explorer, in the Changes section, ready to be committed again

Comment: Then your `.gitignore` file might be wrong, assuming you did `git rm --cached` correctly.

Comment: it is the one the GitHub provides when you create a repo. 
I'm using vs 2015 and I do see comments for 2015 in there 

'# Visual Studo 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/'

Comment: I'll see if I can get a fresh one again

Comment: Post the `.gitnignore` along with the paths of bin folders you want to ignore.

Comment: well that didn't work so well :/ I assume that is what you meant by Post

Comment: No...update your question

Comment: Thanks @Scott Welder for fixing my markdown. Looks a lot better. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

git ignore ignore the file that hadn't been tracked yet, so if a file was committed it will reappear again.

you can try:

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
```

then

```
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095988/2245329)

or go for a more radical approach:

- remove the files with `rm`
- then reset the .git directory (remove it, then initialize it anew with `git init`)
- create a new remote branch
- push to the new branch
- if all looks ok, then merge with the mean branch.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah  this first option failed on me at first. I decided to restart my machine after noticing tortoiseGit started asking me for my password again randomly. I tried it again, and it worked. So maybe there was some caching interfering .. not to sure.. Thankfully I didn't need to do the radical approach.

Comment: some times git ignores gitignore, and it's really annoying, glade that worked out for you :)

Comment: Perfect solution, can't believe the other threads with hundreds of upvotes didn't help me further but this one did

Comment: This is so silly.. why is rider a paid product behaving this way is beyond my understanding....

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even deleting the .git and creating a new repository, he did not ignore it. The problem was in my .gitignore, it is in utf16, I moved to utf8 problem solved!

Comment: this! I created my .gitignore via PowerShell and it created the file with UTF16. After converting it to UTF8 (via Notepad) it worked like a charm. Thank you.

It's a shame that there are dozens of answers saying you just have to 'git rm -r --cached .' but almost none that mention another possible issue like this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already commited something which you now want to ignore, you have to tell git to remove those files from its index with `git rm --cached <files>`

You also need to make sure you have the below in your `.gitignore` file:

```
bin/    # ignore bin directory
*.obj   # ignore any files with .obj postfix
```

Add your commit:

```
 Ignore bin/ directory and any *.obj files
```